# Importing BJT model

Tags: bjt, ltspice

I am trying to import a model into LTspice for HFA3046 transistor but LTspice doesn't seem to recognize this model. Here is the text for the model from the website:
https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/apn/mm3046-hfa3046-hfa3096-hfa3127-hfa3128-spice-model

the model is defined as:

```
.model NUHFARRY NPN

+ (IS = 1.840E - 16 XTI = 3.000E + 00 EG = 1.110E + 00 VAF = 7.200E + 01
+ VAR = 4.500E + 00 BF = 1.036E + 02 ISE = 1.686E - 19 NE = 1.400E + 00
+ IKF = 5.400E - 02 XTB = 0.000E + 00 BR = 1.000E + 01 ISC = 1.605E - 14
+ NC = 1.800E + 00 IKR = 5.400E - 02 RC = 1.140E + 01 CJC = 3.980E - 13
+ MJC = 2.400E - 01 VJC = 9.700E - 01 FC = 5.000E - 01 CJE = 2.400E - 13
+ MJE = 5.100E- 01 VJE = 8.690E - 01 TR = 4.000E - 09 TF = 10.51E - 12
+ ITF = 3.500E - 02 XTF = 2.300E + 00 VTF = 3.500E + 00 PTF = 0.000E + 00
+ XCJC = 9.000E - 01 CJS = 1.150E - 13 VJS = 7.500E - 01 MJS = 0.000E + 00
+ RE = 1.848E + 00 RB = 5.007E + 01 RBM = 1.974E + 00 KF = 0.000E + 00
+ AF = 1.000E + 00)
*
*
```

Does this model have a problem? Here is the setup:
[image]

When I try to plot characteristic curves, nothing shows up. I got rid of a few extra zeros since it was giving a problem about FC having a maximum limit of 0.9999. The error went away after I got rid of the zeros and made it 0.5.
Edit: I removed the blank line and I tried plotting Ic vs Vce for different base currents but I didn't get any curves:
[image]

Edit 2: I tried removing the spaces in the .model description directive and it worked. Here is the new setup:
[image]

Here is the family characteristic curves:
[image]

Comment: Try removing the blank line between "`.model NUHFARRY NPN`" and "`+(IS = 1.840E-16 `...".

Comment: Also tell us exactly what error message you got.

Comment: That didn't do anything. I just tried it.

Comment: What error message did you get?

Comment: There is no error message. Simply there is not current plot when I try to add the collector current trace in the simulator.

Comment: What about removing all the unnecessary spaces in your numbers, like "1.00E+3" instead of "1.00E + 3"?

Comment: If that doesn't work, share your netlist file.

Comment: It worked! thanks!

Comment: Try pulling up the SPICE Error Log (CTRL+L) next time this happens. It should give you hints on what’s wrong with the syntax.